# Multiple POST-request in web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I need to use multiple POST-requests in web API but get an error: "Multiple actions were found that match the request..."

I have 2 POST-requests in my controller:

```
public void PostStart([FromBody]string value)
{
    CookieHeaderValue cookie = Request.Headers.GetCookies("user").FirstOrDefault();
    ...
}


public void PostLogin([FromBody]string value)
{
    CookieHeaderValue cookie = Request.Headers.GetCookies("user").FirstOrDefault();
    ...
}
```

My route file looks like this currently:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "apistart",
        routeTemplate: "Home/api/values/start/{id}",
        defaults: new { action = "PostStart", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "apilogin",
        routeTemplate: "Home/api/values/login/{id}",
        defaults: new { action = "PostLogin", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

If I remove on of the requests from the controller, everything works fine, so my routes seem valid, but when both of requests are present, router can't find the right one.

Any thoughts? 
I've tried alredy to use another default route but it changes nothing:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ActionApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `[HttpPost]` attribute to specify request method:

```
[HttpPost]
public void Start([FromBody]string value)
{
    CookieHeaderValue cookie = Request.Headers.GetCookies("user").FirstOrDefault();
    ...
}

[HttpPost]
public void Login([FromBody]string value)
{
    CookieHeaderValue cookie = Request.Headers.GetCookies("user").FirstOrDefault();
    ...
}
```

That will allows you to use as many post actions as you want with using default action-based route rule.

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ActionApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped, but only with 3 routes. Default couldn't handle it.

Comment: Man, I was having a problem for hours until I found this was the problem..Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should use RouteAttribute to make it work:

```
[Route("start")]
public void PostStart([FromBody]string value)
{
    CookieHeaderValue cookie = Request.Headers.GetCookies("user").FirstOrDefault();
    ...
}

[Route("login")]
public void PostLogin([FromBody]string value)
{
    CookieHeaderValue cookie = Request.Headers.GetCookies("user").FirstOrDefault();
    ...
}
```

WebApi doesn't take into consideration method name, only first word to resolve http method. Thats why you have error which says about "Multiple actions..." - there are two actions which can handle POST request.